# Make sure network request gets executed before app is uninstalled

Tags: ios, networking, urlsession, cfnetwork

I have a PacketTunnel Provider extension running with my app. Once a user un-installs the app I get a call "stopTunnel" with an identifiable reason.

Trying to send a last network request appears to fail. Yet I'm wondering if there might be any low level network options I should try before giving up on this quest?

Happy for suggestions even if they are un-verified. I can try them in my set up.